# Error while launching Pwgui

Tags: 20.04, gui

what can i do with the following error when i want launch pwgui???

```
==================================================
  This is PWgui version: 6.1
 --------------------------------------------------


 PWgui: using the system default "tclsh" interpreter

./pwgui: 79: tclsh: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing [TCL](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tclsh&mode=exactfilename&suite=eoan&arch=any). You can install it using command:

```
sudo apt install tcl
```